# GroupBy a columns for each n rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group a dataframe based on a column for each n rows. The input is:

```
    A

0   1
1   2
3   1
4   2
5   3
6   2
7   1
8   2
9   2
```

I want to group by 'A' column for every 3 rows, thus my output should be:

```
    A

0   1
1   2
4   2
5   3
7   1
8   2
```

And after possibly reset the index in order to obtain:

```
    A

0   1
1   2
2   2
3   3
4   1
5   2
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is no clear to me , can you clarify why you can get the optput ? by sum? or mean ?

Comment: I have an aggregation function, but that is not the core. What I am not able to do is to select a frame in the dataset in which I need to execute the grouping.@Wen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC...

```
df.groupby((np.array(range(len(df))))//3).A.apply(lambda x : x.drop_duplicates())
Out[156]: 
0  0    1
   1    2
1  4    2
   5    3
2  7    1
   8    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```